# Can I use http to pull images from the Docker registry?

Tags: docker

I am using a transparent caching proxy on my network, and I don't want to MITM all the SSL traffic.

Is there a way to get Docker to use HTTP instead of HTTPS to get images from the official registry? From what I gather, it's using sha256 sums to validate the images anyway so I wouldn't be lowering security?

Am I missing something or would it be ok to use HTTP? And how to tell Docker to use HTTP when pulling images?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "official registry", do you mean Docker Hub? If so, Docker Hub supports only `https`. However, it is possible to use the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` behind an `http` proxy. Below are the steps:

1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
   ```
2. Create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable used by the docker daemon:

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
   ```
3. Reload systemd and restart docker:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

More info is in https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy.

http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/11/using-docker-with-a-proxy.html is a nice blog about using docker behind a proxy.